# SMTPServerDisconnected at /password-reset/

Tags: django, smtp

Connection unexpectedly closed: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

Less secure app access are allowed on my gmail account

Comment: I recommend using `os.environ['EMAIL_USER']` and `os.environ['EMAIL_PASS']`, to avoid silent failures when the environment variables aren't set. Note that there are lots of questions from people having trouble using gmail with Django. If the suggestions there do not help, it might be easier to use a different email provider.

Comment: yeah it didn't help , and i made an app before with same method and it worked , idk why its throwing an error now.